# Apply 'Zurich BT', a font with a space in the name

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I have two codes to achieve the size = 11 and type = Zurich Bt.

The first code gives me font type Zurich Bt but size =36 when I have opted 11.

```
strBody1 = "<font size=11pt face=""Zurich Bt"" color=""Black"">" & _
      "This is my Body." "</font>"
```

The second code gives me size 11 but font type doesn't change to Zurich Bt instead it shows Zurich in Outlook which isn't any font in the list.

```
strBody1 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Zurich Bt> This is my Body. </BODY>"
```

Comment: The first example uses the Html element font.  I believe this has been dropped from the latest version of Html although most browsers will recognise it.  The attribute size can have a value between 1 and 7.  3 means you want the default size; 1 or 2 mean you want a smaller font while 4, 5, 6 and 7 mean you want a larger font.

Comment: The second example uses CCS.  The recommended use of font-size is "font-size=medium" or "font-size=large".  Absolute lengths such as "font-size= 11pt" are not recommended unless you know the nature of the output device.  It is not clear how many browsers support the unit pt.

Comment: I suggest you look at a up-to-date specification.  Type "CCS font" into your favourite search engine and your will be shown pages on how to use these styles.

Comment: I am using it in outlook body. ie .htmlbody = strBody1. I want specifically Zurich BT and 11pt  size and type in there

Comment: It does not matter what you want.  What is important, is what the recipients of such emails can handle.  I do not have “Zurich BT” on my system.  Apparently, it is a free download.  You cannot rely on your recipients having this font.  I typed “outlook: what html version does it use?” into Bing and got several sites providing useful information.  Apparently, no email package supports all features of Html or Css.  If any of your recipients use smartphones to view your emails, do not use fixed font sizes such as “pt” or “px”.

Comment: I got your point. But still for 2nd point How do I get 11px ? because if I chose 3 it gives me 10px if I chose 4 it gives me 12px. How do you get 11px ? I have tries 3.1 to 3.9, none works.

Comment: Your first example uses straight Html.  With Html, font-size has no unit; it is simply a number between 1 and 7 to indicate relative size.  Your second example uses Css.  With Css, font-size does have a unit; choices include px and em.  Search for "CSS font-size property" and you will find lots of helpful advice.

Comment: The Css format you have used is to have attribute style within an Html start tag.  The alternative is to specify formats in the Html document header so they apply to all occurrences of an Html element or all occurrences of an Html element with a particular class. This alternative is the preferred format so it is usually specified first.  However, I understand GMail cannot handle this format because it ignores anything in the Html header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tony I appreciate all the effort made by you. But I was looking for specific solution, which I have found out now. To get Zurich BT font or any other font which got space between them, you just need to put single quote. Please find below for the reference who are struggling with same issue.

```
style='font-size:11pt;font-family:Zurich Bt'
```